Does an .ovpn override the .mobileconfig dns settings?
I am using a MacOS with a specific .mobileconfig installed on it which doesn’t allow the users to change dns over https. I am curious if the user is allowed to use open vpn, will the connection on open vpn override the dns configured by .mobileconfig?
Thank you.
